# How to backup as insert sql on delete data?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

In order to easily restore the data after the wrong operation, I hope that the SQL of the deleted data can be backed up when the data is deleted, so as to restore the data.

What is the solution?

Comment: trigger on delete write to another table , or soft delete existing table , or backup before delete(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively straightforward solution is to add a `deleted` flag on entities and just update that flag.

Then you need to add a new clause to all your queries, but you can also use filters to exclude deleted objects:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "deletedFilter")
@Filter(name = "deletedFilter", condition = "deleted = 0")
public class DeleteableEntity {
  private boolean deleted;
```

And then:

```
session.enableFilter("deletedFilter");
```